# How can I configure MPU(Memory Protection Unit) for an OS_Task in Vector AUTOSAR Conguration Tool?

Tags: autosar, mpu

I want to protect an OS_Task using MPU in Vector AUTOSAR Conguration Tool. How can I do?

Comment: You can find a high level guide in section "3.17 Memory Protection" of `TechnicalReference_Os.pdf` in your SIP.
Please work through this and then feel free to ask specific questions. However, then we will need a lot more information, which you probably cannot write in public here.

Answer (score 1):

For a configured task, you configure `OsTaskMemoryProtectionIdentifier` to specify a memory protection identifier for the task. you set the protection ID.

If this parameter is not set but the owner OS-Application has a memory protection identifier specified this value will be used for the task.

Memory protection identifier are configured inside `Os/OsPublishedInformation/OsDerivativeInformation/OsMemoryRegionSpecifics`

Depending on the used platform protection identifiers are also referred as PID (MPC),
ASID (RH850) or protection sets (TriCore)